# Editr.js light theme

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to figure out how to implement the [editr.js](https://github.com/Idered/Editr.js/blob/master/README.md) light theme

It says it to do it via JS,

Not overly sure what it means in the documentation when it says

> ACE Editor theme. If you want to use light theme then also add class editr--light.

How do i go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line, add "editr--light" to the list of classes:

```
<div class="editr" data-item="PROJECT-NAME" data-files-html="index-1.html;index-2.html" data-files-css="!normalize.css;style.css" data-files-js="!jquery.js;script.js"></div>
```

EG:

```
<div class="editr editr--light" data-item="PROJECT-NAME" data-files-html="index-1.html;index-2.html" data-files-css="!normalize.css;style.css" data-files-js="!jquery.js;script.js"></div>
```

NOTE: you may want to switch libraries... their [main domain](http://lab.idered.pl) is [up for auction](http://www.aftermarket.pl/domena/idered.pl?nostat=1).

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything for me. I still get the dark color in the result window. Also i noticed that they still have a page at http://lab.kasper.io/editr/ . Regarding switching libraries. i have also struggled to find any other similar libraries to substitute.

Comment: To be clear im trying to get the permanent white background in the results window. Perhaps im getting something wrong here

Comment: Nevermind, I totally misunderstood what to do, I had to set the results window background via CSS. Although for the question i asked, you are correct, so i will mark as correct as my question was wrong not the answer.

Comment: You may want to check out https://www.tinymce.com/ and http://ckeditor.com/ those are the big names that come to mind.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but this is kind of like codepen. I cannot find another standalone JS library that has the results from the editor live like this, and with Gist support